# I want to take the mean of all but one column on a data frame I have

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with about 11 columns but one of those columns is ID numbers. I want to take the mean of all the columns except that one (since that wouldn't make sense to take the mean of). I'm aware of `df.mean(axis=0)` but that takes the mean of the ID column. Is there a way to say "take the mean of all the columns after the first one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'unwantedColumn'].mean()
```

Comment: I am glad it worked for you ! Don't forget to mark the answer as the selected answer for the benefit of other readers.